# powershell : get the inf file name of a device

Tags: windows, usb, powershell, inf

Using the device manager I am able to retrieve the inf file name of a device, is there command in Powershell capable to give the inf file name ? I need it because I am using devcon to install my usb devices with a script.

I had a look at `Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControllerDevice` and `Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive` but neither of these commands seem to give information about the inf file of the device.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: [Life in PowerShell: Identify the only drivers a machine needs for the OSD driver import process in Configuration Manager](https://lifeinpowershell.blogspot.com/2014/02/identify-only-drivers-machine-needs-for.html) should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: And [How to Extract certain driver from windows – Martin Buist – IT Blogger](http://www.martinbuist.com/powershell/how-to-extract-certain-driver-from-windows/)

Comment: maybe this helps `get-ciminstance win32_pnpsigneddriver` there's a property `InfName` returning stuff like this: `ndisvirtualbus.inf`

Answer (score 1):

Try `Get-CimInstance win32_PnPSignedDriver` and look for the `InfName` Property

Example Output:

```
Caption                 :
Description             : USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
InstallDate             :
Name                    :
Status                  :
CreationClassName       :
Started                 :
StartMode               :
SystemCreationClassName :
SystemName              :
ClassGuid               : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
CompatID                : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&REV_04
DeviceClass             : USB
DeviceID                : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&SUBSYS_3396103C&REV_04\3&11583659&0&A0
DeviceName              : USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
DevLoader               :
DriverDate              : 10.08.2017 02:00:00
DriverName              :
DriverProviderName      : Microsoft
DriverVersion           : 10.0.14393.1794
FriendlyName            : Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible-Hostcontroller – 1.0 (Microsoft)
HardWareID              : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E31&SUBSYS_3396103C&REV_04
InfName                 : usbxhci.inf
IsSigned                : True
Location                : PCI bus 0, device 20, function 0
Manufacturer            : Generic USB xHCI Host Controller
PDO                     : \Device\NTPNP_PCI0002
Signer                  : Microsoft Windows
PSComputerName          :
```

Comment: Thanks, the only issue is that this command provides information about the driver that are already installed. As I am writing a script that will install usb device, I need to retrieve the inf file name when the device is not installed yet, just like I can do it using the device manager but I am starting to believe that it is not possible....